# How do I check if my object is properly disposed?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, memory-management, dispose

I wonder if there a "trick" that permits to know if the used objects in a portion o code has been properly(entirely) disposed, or, in other words don't creates memory leaks.

Let's say I have a container of GDI objects (or other that I need to explicitly dispose)

```
public class SuperPen 
{
    Pen _flatPen, _2DPen, _3DPen;
    public SuperPen() 
    {
        _flatPen = (Pen)Pens.Black.Clone();
        _2DPen = (Pen)Pens.Black.Clone();
        _3DPen = (Pen)Pens.Black.Clone();
    }
}
```

Now, as I need to Dispose the GDI objects I do:

```
public class SuperPen : IDisposable
{
    Pen _flatPen, _2DPen, _3DPen;
    public SuperPen()
    {
        _flatPen = (Pen)Pens.Black.Clone();
        _2DPen = (Pen)Pens.Black.Clone();
        _3DPen = (Pen)Pens.Black.Clone();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_flatPen != null) { _flatPen.Dispose(); _flatPen = null; }
        // HERE a copy paste 'forget', should be _2DPen instead
        if (_flatPen != null) { _flatPen.Dispose(); _flatPen = null; }
        if (_3DPen != null) { _3DPen.Dispose(); _3DPen = null; }
    }
}
```

Situation like this can happen if you add a new "disposable" object and forget to dispose it etc. How can I detect my error, I mean, check if my SuperPen was properly disposed?

Comment: My spontaneous though is "why do you clone `Pens.Black`"? But it is perhaps used only to illustrate the question?

Comment: @Frederik: Just is a way to initialize a "Empty" pen. I could do also `= new Pen(Color.Black);` - do it because show that my object has been created and finally will need a dispose/memory free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think it is possible; the best you can do is to get a profiler (such as [ants profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/code_profiling.htm)) and measure it. If you find that you are leaking memory excessively ( via the profiler), then there is something wrong.

Other than using profiler, I am not sure of any automatic techniques that help you identify undisposed resources.

Comment: If it's not possible, how does ANTS do it?

Comment: @Dan: I'm guessing via the profiling API: http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2003/Internals/Profiling.htm

Comment: @280Z28: I meant it as a rhetorical question--I'm pretty sure the fact that ANTS does it (via a .NET API, no less) means that it *is* possible. That said, I certainly wouldn't do it myself when something like ANTS already exists.

Answer (score 1):

A tool such as [MemProfiler](http://memprofiler.com/) or [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm) will identify memory leaks (both have trial versions).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this [pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx), which incorporates a destructor to ensure than un-disposed items are cleaned up.  This will catch anything that you're not calling 'dispose' on, and is a good fail safe.

Comment: This *especially* applies to release builds: you should not override the finalizer for any object that doesn't *directly* hold *unmanaged* resources due to an unnecessary and significant performance overhead. Unmanaged resources should almost always be held in a class derived from `SafeHandle` (or similar) to reduce the load on the GC as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe FxCop (available standalone or integrated into the Team System versions of VS2005+) will detect this.